# Lua's package management system?

Tags: lua, package-managers

What's the Lua's standard package management system and repository? Like `brew` for *Mac OS X*, `npm` for `node.js`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to distribute Lua and libraries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065783/whats-the-best-way-to-distribute-lua-and-libraries)

Comment: This question asks the opposite - how to install modules easily from a centralized package repository, like `brew` and `npm`, so I do not consider it a duplicate.

Comment: @MichalKottman Oh T_T...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There is no *standard* Lua package management system, but you can try out the following:

- [LuaRocks](http://luarocks.org/) - contains a rather large number of Lua modules distributed as [*rocks*](http://luarocks.org/repositories/rocks/). Once LuaRocks is installed, the installation is simple: `luarocks install desired-package`. On Linux/Unix/Mac, this will install into `/usr/local/{share,lib}/lua/5.1`, where the Lua interpreter looks for modules.
- [LuaDist](http://luadist.org/) - designed to create an independent standalone directory with Lua and modules (a *dist*). Everything in LuaDist is CMake-based, which means that it can be easily compiled using any compiler/IDE supported by CMake. LuaDist also has an extensive [repository](https://github.com/LuaDist/Repository) which contains Lua modules and also many C dependencies/libraries, which allows to create a truly independent Lua "distribution". Installation is the same as with LuaRocks - `luadist install desired-package`.

Comment: How about uninstall/remove/purge/clean feature? Can they handle these functions well?

Comment: I've never had to uninstall :) But I'm sure they do, let me see... `luarocks remove`, and `luadist remove`.