# How third-party libraries in Lua usually handled

Tags: lua, love2d

How third-party libraries in Lua usually handled?

For example, I want to use the [HUMP](https://github.com/vrld/hump) library for my [LÖVE](https://love2d.org/) application.

What should I do then? Is there any popular package manager? Or should I just place libraries under "vendor" / "libs" directory in the project's root folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lua's package management system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797451/luas-package-management-system)

Comment: For Lua package management see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797451/luas-package-management-system

You can place libraries wherever it suits your needs. If you use them exclusively for one project then have it with the project. If you don't like that or you share it across several projects use a common folder...

Answer (score 3):

Lua uses a package manager called [LuaRocks](https://luarocks.org/).

However, [HUMP](https://github.com/vrld/hump), and most other third party libraries for [LOVE](https://love2d.org/) do not have a  *rock* (package) for LuaRocks, and thus cannot be installed/handled that way. There is no definitive convention for including 3rd-party libraries in a LOVE project. It's usually up to the project developer. However, there is a [Thread](https://love2d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=82381&hilit=3rd%20party%20library%20organize) on the forum where people talk about how they organize their projects that should be of use to you.